# How can I get Outlook to recognize daylight savings time?

Tags: outlook, timezone, icalendar, dst, timezone-offset

I have an ics file that a user is trying to import into Outlook for Mac 2011.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:anonymized
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Prague
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20140330T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=5SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20141026T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=4SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140807T001736Z
UID:12345
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Prague:20140808T090000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Prague:20140808T100000
CREATED:20140805T162858Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20140806T052758Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:confirmed
SUMMARY:My event for which everyone with Outlook will be an hour late to
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Every other calendar program displays this event at 9:00am in Prague, but Outlook is displaying it at 10:00am. It appears that Outlook is using the `STANDARD` block in the `VTIMEZONE` to calculate the time and never applying a DST offset. I think that because removing the `STANDARD` block entirely or changing `TZOFFSETTO` inside the `STANDARD` block to `+0200` results in the event being displayed at the correct time.

Both of those are obviously non-starters as they would break every other calendar application on the face of the planet.

Am I missing something about specifying timezones for Outlook's consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook was not able to handle the recurrence rule for the `DAYLIGHT` block in the example timezone.

Changing the `VTIMEZONE` definition to:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Prague
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20140330T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20141026T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

allowed Outlook to correctly display the event.

The only change is changing both `RRULE` definitions to be `BYDAY=-1SU`. This has the double benefit of allowing Outlook to parse it and being a more correct expansion of the rules around CEST/CET transitions than `5SU`/`4SU` was.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the timezone settings in Outlook. It may display your event as seen from another timezone.
Another way to check would bet to create an event from outlook and export it to ics to see what timezone it uses for that event.

Comment: My copy of Outlook is set to eastern timezone in the US, which means this actual event is displaying at 4:00am. But it should be displaying at 3:00am, like it does on every other calendar application. My user's is set to Prague and has the 9am/10am problem laid out in the question.